# Intellij go import autocomplete

Tags: go, intellij-idea

Anyway to have Intellij autocomplete import statements for github projects?

Like if I want to import `github.com/gorilla/mux` but I haven't run `go get ...` yet, is there anyway to have that be autocompleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I haven't run `go get` ... yet, is there anyway to have that be autocompleted?

No: [Gogland](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/) should add the import automatically on save, but only if the package was installed first (present in a `pkg` folder of your workspace, for external packages)

And even in that case, Gogland will not automatically import ambiguous packages (meaning if you have two `rand` packages, it will ask you which one to use, the `crypto/rand` or the `math/rand`). That should not be the case here.

Comment: Thanks! Also, I have my env setup this way:

Under `~/go-projects`, I have `src/`, `bin/` and `pkg/`. 

Under `src/` I have all my projects. Now, when I run `go get -t github.com/gorilla/mux` from inside `src/project-1`, the package gets installed under `~/go-projects/src/`. Is that how it should be? Or should it get installed under `~/go-projects/pkg/` ?

Comment: @NishantRoy a `go get` or `go get -u` should be enough to download the sources (in `src` as you mention), compile and install in `pkg` (`*.a` files)